# Build Run time stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Can i know is there any way to construct a stored procedure at run time. I will be dealing with stored procedure . So instead of creating a stored procedure manually, just passing the parameters to a generic sp which just gets those values and constructs a new stored procedure . Am just asking like a tool which generates new stored procedure and the tool is itself a stored procedure.

Hope am clear.

Comment: what is your requirement ... why do you need a stored procedure to be genereated as an output and what is the resultant stored procedure supposed to do

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sql-  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: SQL is a _query language_, not a DBMS product.

Comment: I mean Microsoft Sql server

Comment: may i get any suggestions